# How can I give input to GWT FileUpload using Selenium WebDriver?

Tags: gwt, selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I need to give a input text file in GWT **FileUpload** and test it using Selenium Webdriver.

I have Upload widget, In that I need to give a text file as input. Then click a upload button to do my functionality.

[image]

i tried this,

```
driver.findElement(By.id("uploadField")).sendKeys("C:/Desktop/Input.txt");
driver.findElement(By.id("uploadButton")).click();
```

but I'm not able to give input to this upload field.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Plz show what you are trying and what's the problem you are facing?

Comment: He is trying to invoke systems file browser from Selenium. This was not possible in Selenium 1.

Comment: Ok Then how can I achieve this? I'm wokring in Selenium2 WebDriver

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this code is working for me see : use correct file path in sendkeys

```
         driver.get("http://www.freepdfconvert.com/");
     driver.findElement(By.id("UploadedFile")).sendKeys("C:\\Users\\username\\Downloads\\HP1.pdf");      
     try {
         Thread.sleep(4000);
        } 
         catch (Exception e) {}
     driver.findElement(By.name("pdfsubmit")).click();
        }
```

or

```
  driver.findElement(By.id("uploadField")).sendKeys("C:/xyz.txt");
  driver.findElement(By.name("uploadButton")).click();
```

Use name or Xpath then check .

**Edit**

Yes it run for all browser but for IE and chrome you have to add small code.
IE:

```
DesiredCapabilities ieCapabilities = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer(); 
           ieCapabilities.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.INTRODUCE_FLAKINESS_BY_IGNORING_SECURITY_DOMAINS, true);
             WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(ieCapabilities);
```

Chrome

```
    File file = new File("E://chromedriver.exe");
    System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", file.getAbsolutePath());
    WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();`
```

Comment: Its working. Thanks. Mistake is I used '/' instead of '\' i.e '\\'. I updated now to '\\'. Its working. Great answer. Thanks.